# Apache Mesos - cases pro and contra containers?

Tags: containers, orchestration

My current impression is, Apache Mesos was introduced before the LXC container technology became *easily* available (via Docker).

So you could implement "your own Apache Mesos Java framework" for example, or use Marathon to do that.

Now, Marathon seems to support containers as well.

Question - when would you deploy Java nowadays on/with Mesos/Marathon without contauners? And if you use containers, why should you opt for Mesos instead of for example Kubernetes?

For example, [here](https://logz.io/blog/kubernetes-vs-mesos/) they say in my understanding, k8s ecosystem deployment is easier while with Mesos you would have to opt for the enterprise version of DC/OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your impression is false, linux containers (LXC) exists since 2008, mesos and docker have started later. All three makes use of cgroups available since kernel 2.6.28.

For your overall question, mesosphere have a [blog post](https://mesosphere.com/blog/docker-vs-kubernetes-vs-apache-mesos/) about it.

But mainly you're looking at it from the wrong point of view, choosing the underlying orchestration system should not be done from 'how to deploy this application?' point of view, but more on 'What would be the best orchestration for what I have to deploy as a whole ?'. Making the choice between swarm/kubernetes/mesos/k8s on mesos/swarm on mesos/whatever is very dependent on your environment, your existing knowledge, your team skills etc. and we can"'t really help you choose without an extended description on what you're willing to manage.

Comment: "linux containers (LXC) exists since 2008" I've added "easily avalable"

Comment: @PeterMuryshkin easily is very personal, I did found legacy lxc easier to work with than docker for a bunch of cases, either you're asking about docker (and in this case yes, mesos was a little earlier than docker, 2k11 vs 2k13) ,marathon was in 2k14 but would more compare to swarm). All in all, the blog post I linked gives the general difference nowadays and the uses cases, the answer stands after the edit as it is still the same, choosing the underlying orchestration should not be taken from a single application point of view but from a global architecture point of view.